# Simple Spring Boot Hello World Example Using JSP

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Got a problem testing Spring Boot app. Whatever I try to do it's not working for some reason. Thought about an issue with embedded Tomcat and JSP compiling problem, even added another compiler. Yet not working.

Probably the error is somewhere on the surface.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

SpringServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

And Controller

```
@Controller
public class BootController {
private String message = "Hello World!";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("message", this.message);
    return "index";
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Accessing localhost shows whitelabel error page.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywtYf.png)

**UPDATE**

---

When I'm trying to repackage project using `mvn spring-boot:repackage` I get the following error log:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 5.172 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-16T14:34:36+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/153M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-
plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default-cli) on project demo: Execution 
default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-
plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage failed: Source must refer to an existing file 
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Still thinking what it can be. I expect this to be some repackaging problem, i can't really track simply because can't make any changes in the project. However, if I create `@RestController` and just return string, it works fine.

Comment: What url are you trying to access?

Comment: @MicD i'm starting tomcat on 8080 port, accessing `localhost:8080` and expect to see index.jsp page as I mapped the controller on `/`. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: Spring boot may not need port (I think I had such issue ones). Try localhost/

Comment: @MicD well, not worked for me. But thanks.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Try this tutorial  : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: @Pete no errors absolutely.

Comment: @gladiator yes, bumped into that one once. The thing is that I tried to make everything exactly the same as Mkyong's, however got the same result. Whitelabel page.

Comment: try adding jslt dependency 
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: @gladiator tried that one too. Still nothing changed.

Comment: I think its because of  embedded tomcat .Check this link from spring boot docs.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: I just downloaded the tutorial from mkyong (ref. by  @gladiator), modified with spring boot version **1.5.3.RELEASE** and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in embedded tomcat try these deps:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Well, if it works for others, I expect it to work for me. Otherwise, there is something wrong with my configs or system probably. And I want to find out what.

Comment: okay, with that response i assume you are running in an embedde tomcat, see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```